# White Background on the whole website length

Tags: html, css

I have a display problem in my web site content.
I am creating a website and it displays well on the browser (width 100%) But when I resize the browser screen and I made a transition to the right with the bottom scroll bar a white background appeared. 
I'm not using the responsive technique.
I work with a fixed container width (width: 1170px; margin: 0 auto;)

the website: http://www.lemediterranee.com.tn/medet/

Comment: What browser (and version) are using for testing?

Comment: I'm using Google Chrome, the lastest version

Answer (score 1):

Add background-size: cover to main.

```
main{
   background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to clear the white background by adding extra style to the `main` custom element:

```
-webkit-background-size: cover;
-moz-background-size: cover;
-o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
```

Also added prefixes for cross-browser support.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not using responsive design, make your header with an fixed with

```
.top_header {
background-color: #222d68;
width: 1170px;
height: 45px;
}
```

Make your slider and main container with fixed width too

```
#slideshow {
float: left;
width: 1170px;
position: relative;
z-index: 8;
border-bottom: 3px solid rgb(194, 194, 194);
}

main {
background-image: url("../img/backgrounds/main_bg.jpg");
background-repeat: no-repeat;
height: 1075px;
float: left;
width: 1170px;
}
```

For the footer to

```
.bottom_footer {
width: 1170px;
height: 45px;
background-color: #222222;
float: left;
}
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it partially solve the preobleme, but I do not want change for example the width of the top header, I want that this element must always have the 100% width of the browser

Comment: The problem is that your website has some fluid and fixed elements.  Your container class has a width of 1170px. It makes the horizontal scrollbar to appear, and, therefore, all elements that have width of 100% will follow the screen, making the white backgroud appear. You should make the container have width 100% and make some adjustments, to make your website more fluid.

Comment: I don't get why this answer got so many down votes. He said that he was not using responsive elements, so he should have made all classes with fixed width.